# PayPal Native checkout card errors

Tags: android, paypal

Can anyone help with my issue please?
I have implemented the andoid PayPalNativeCheckout SDK and all is working. The native code logs on and brings up a wallet giving the option for PayPal Credit, PayPal Balance and add a credit card.

My question is do I need to check that the payment has been authorised against all possibilities such as insufficient funds, card expired, stolen inaccurate expiry or CVC code or does the SDK do that for me as part of the flow.

The status of the order within paypal is changed to APPROVED so all appears find, just need to know for sure as the wallet doesn't allow forcing of errors.

There is a listener in the SDK called onPayPalCheckoutFailure which I'm hoping is called if the PayPal SDK will call if there are any issues and the payment can't be processed.

Thanks.

Added following response/comment

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've mostly got it, but are missing the capture that should happen after successful approval. "APPROVED" means a payer signed in and clicked the final button (Pay Now or Continue), it does *not* mean there is a PayPal transaction. You need an Order capture call for that, and based on the result of the capture call is when you either display success/thank you or (similar to the onPayPalCheckoutFailure approval failure case) say there was a problem and have the payer to go back.

Comment: Thanks, I do the capture afterwards so are you saying that even though the "Order" is showing as APPROVED, the payment could still be rejected for an invalid card/lack of funds etc? I've added the image above for the Orders api. Presumably one of these is chosen. Currently I'm only getting COMPLETED as I cant find a way to forced card errors.